# Link not re-directing to a page in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to make a Navbar but the  isn't re-directing to the given page. If I click any of the links in the Navbar, it would change the path in the url bar but won't re-direct to that page. I am not sure if I am missing anything. When I replace it with the  tags, it works perfectly.

Navbar.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/articles">Articles</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/articles-all">All articles</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default Navbar;
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css'

//pages
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import About from "./Pages/About";
import Articles from "./Pages/Articles";
import ArticlesList from "./Pages/ArticlesList";

//components
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar/>
      <Navigation />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div id="page-body">
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/articles" component={Articles} />
          <Route path="/articles-all" component={ArticlesList} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: Remove `Router,Switch` from your `Navbar` component and add it to `Navigation`

Comment: That's why I did earlier, but was getting the error `Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>` in the Navbar.js

Comment: Let me correct this for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you define the Router within Navigation and another one in `Navbar` your Links are not able to communicate to the Router Component in Navigation as they just communicate to their nearest parent Router component

You must you use a single Router instance to be able to perform seemless navigation within your App. Also a Switch component is not needed with Links  but with `Route`

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Router component={Navbar}/>     // rendered as default route so that they receive router props
      <Router component={Navigation} />
    </Router>
  );
};
export default App;

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
      <div id="page-body">
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/articles" component={Articles} />
          <Route path="/articles-all" component={ArticlesList} />
      </div>
  );
};


const Navbar = () => {
  return (
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/articles">Articles</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/articles-all">All articles</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

  );
};
export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working codesandbox URL https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-black-3i8hp?file=/src/App.js

You were wrapping links with browserRouter and Switch. These APIs are intended to wrap Routes only.

So, It wasn't able to communicate well with your react app.